# spark.executor.extraJavaOptions ignored in spark-submit

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop

I am a newbie trying to profile a local spark job.
Here is the command that I am trying to execute, but I am getting a warning stating my executor options are being ignored since they are non-spark config properties.

error:

> Warning: Ignoring non-spark config property: “spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=javaagent:statsd-jvm-profiler-2.1.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar=server=localhost,port=8086,reporter=InfluxDBReporter,database=profiler,username=profiler,password=profiler,prefix=MyNamespace.MySparkApplication,tagMapping=namespace.application”

Command:

> ./bin/spark-submit --master local[2] --class org.apache.spark.examples.GroupByTest --conf “spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-javaagent:statsd-jvm-profiler-2.1.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar=server=localhost,port=8086,reporter=InfluxDBReporter,database=profiler,username=profiler,password=profiler,prefix=MyNamespace.MySparkApplication,tagMapping=namespace.application”  --name HdfsWordCount  --jars /Users/shprin/statD/statsd-jvm-profiler-2.1.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar libexec/examples/jars/spark-examples_2.11-2.3.0.jar

Spark version : 2.0.3

Please let me know, how to solve this.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Can you please remove the quotes around `spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=...` and start over? I'd rather do `--conf spark.executor.extraJavaOptions="-javaagent:statsd-jvm-profiler-2.1.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar=server=localhost,port=8086,reporter=InfluxDBReporter,database=profiler,username=profiler,password=profiler,prefix=MyNamespace.MySparkApplication,tagMapping=namespace.application"` or even without the quotes.

Comment: Tried that didn't work1

Comment: What was the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is the double quote you are using to specify the spark.executor.extraJavaOptions. It should have been a single quote.

> ./bin/spark-submit --master local[2]  --conf 'spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-javaagent:statsd-jvm-profiler-2.1.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar=server=localhost,port=8086,reporter=InfluxDBReporter,database=profiler,username=profiler,password=profiler,prefix=MyNamespace.MySparkApplication,tagMapping=namespace.application' --class org.apache.spark.examples.GroupByTest --name HdfsWordCount --jars /Users/shprin/statD/statsd-jvm-profiler-2.1.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar libexec/examples/jars/spark-examples_2.11-2.3.0.jar

Comment: Single/double quote is not required around spark.executor.extraJavaOptions. Single/double quote should be around the options.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from answers above, if your parameter contains both spaces and single quotes (for instance a query paramter) you should enclose it with in escaped double quote \"

Example:

```
spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster --conf "spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-DfileFormat=PARQUET -Dquery=\"select * from bucket where code in ('A')\" -Dchunk=yes" spark-app.jar
```

Comment: I had to provide space b/w two options as mentioned in this answer. Comma didnt work.